# rsync: Connection timed out

Tags: rsync

I am not able to list drectories through rsync:

**from Host2:**

```
user@host2#sudo rsync user@host1::share
rsync: failed to connect to host1: Connection timed out (110)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(122) [Receiver=3.0.7]
```

---

It does not show rsync as a service

```
user@host2#nmap host1_IP //(IP of host1)

PORT      STATE  SERVICE
20/tcp    closed ftp-data
21/tcp    open   ftp
22/tcp    open   ssh
23/tcp    open   telnet
25/tcp    open   smtp
53/tcp    open   domain
80/tcp    open   http
81/tcp    closed hosts2-ns
110/tcp   open   pop3
143/tcp   open   imap
443/tcp   open   https
465/tcp   closed smtps
587/tcp   open   submission
783/tcp   closed spamassassin
990/tcp   closed ftps
993/tcp   closed imaps
995/tcp   closed pop3s
3306/tcp  open   mysql
7025/tcp  closed unknown
8080/tcp  open   http-proxy
8081/tcp  closed blackice-icecap
10000/tcp closed snet-sensor-mgmt
```

Could rsync be hidden behind a firewall?

Comment: RSync doesn't have to have its own service on the remote machine. I RSync from my server through SSH mostly. using `user@host::/home/user/folder`. That will hook into SSH for file transfers.

Comment: Syntax to run over ssh is user@host:/home/user/folder (you provided two colon).

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using rsync via ssh, you need to have rsyncd running on the remote side.

For the firewall, make sure port 873 is open for tcp.

Assuming /etc/services is correct, you might open it for udp 873 as well.

```
$ egrep rsync /etc/services
rsync       873/tcp
rsync       873/udp
```